# Having to close the shop Vs. closing the shop

Tags: meaning-in-context, gerunds

I read this sentence: " If you could see how worried Mum is about having to close the shop, you couldn’t fail to see that money is really important.”

If I write" ...how worried Mum is about closing the shop,..."

Or If I write: If you could see how worried Mum is to close the shop,..."

How would these changes alter the meaning of the sentence?

Comment: _Closing the shop_ gives no indication of being forced to do so; it could even refer to closing at the end of the day rather than closing down the business.

Comment: Thanks @Kate Bunting